# Why bother with RDNS?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, reverse-dns

What are the advantages of setting up reverse DNS?  I have a VPS with one static IP address, where I host several web apps each with its own domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll be sending mail from your VPS, it's in your best interest to set up a `PTR` record, lest your mail be frequently flagged as spam. Many mail servers check to verify that a sending server has a `PTR` record and, in many cases, that it matches that server's `A` record.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particular advantage in clients or web servers having RDNS.

Mail originators *should* have it though, as it's an important part of the anti-spam validation process.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare's ESX/ESXi products won't work in a HA cluster without both records, that's pretty worthwhile to me.